# How can I show the reciprocal number in upper triangle of league table?

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ys0f.jpg)I use netleague order in netmeta package of R for my network meta analysis

```
netleague(net2, digits = 2, ci = FALSE)
```

However, it showed indirect effect in lower triangle and direct effect in upper triangle.

I just want it to show the reciprocal number in the upper triangle for league table instead of direct effect

Additionally, I used this order

```
netleague(net1, net1, seq = netrank(net1), ci = FALSE, backtransf = FALSE)
```

To combine and try to show upper triangle as the the reciprocal number but still cannot.

I have tried to find many solutions but still cannot.

Comment: It's a **triangle** - not a "traingle" ...

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a matrix, then we can use `lower.tri` and `upper.tri`.

```r
m <- matrix(c(1,2,NA,3), nr=2)
m
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1   NA
# [2,]    2    3
m[upper.tri(m)] <- 1/m[lower.tri(m)]
m
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1  0.5
# [2,]    2  3.0
```

Comment: it  must turn to be 1/value for upper triangle.  for example if lower triangel is 0.3, upper must be = 1/0.3 = 3.33

Comment: Just divide it? See my edit, @PanitanaPithaka

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try after finishing my work and let you know how it works or not

Comment: I added a photo of my data since I have not run it and you may imagine more about my question. May you answer me again? thank you

Comment: Your data is not numeric, so you need to parse it out. FYI, an image of data is just that, an image, it is nothing we can use to work on your code. Please use `dput(.)` or `data.frame(..)` or `read.table(..)` for sharing sample data in its true form (R console has a way of hiding important attributes of data), see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for discussions on using those and how to make sure a question is self-contained and reproducible.

Comment: I could not send my question so I used a photo to explain all from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78248589/how-can-i-make-the-reciprocal-1-value-number-as-risk-ratio-of-lower-triangle-i

Comment: I m appreciative about your help but I really cannot write a suiatble question and send so I posted the photo from R console instead

Comment: I'm out. I don't have `netleague`, I'm not going to guess at how the object is really structured (if not just a trivial `matrix` with additional attributes), and I'm not going to transcribe data you have readily available on your console (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 for why images of code/data are discouraged).