# How can I make the reciprocal (1/value) number as risk ratio of lower triangle in upper triangle of my league table?

Tags: r

it showed indirect effect in the lower triangle and direct effect in the upper triangle.

[image]

It showed indirect effect in the lower triangle and direct effect in the upper triangle.
I just want it to show the reciprocal number in the upper triangle for league table instead of direct effect or what about function for calculating from R

I tried this order netleague(net1, net1, seq = netrank(net1), ci = FALSE, backtransf = FALSE)
to combine another league table and to show upper triangle as the the reciprocal number but still cannot.

I tried to use matrix but still cannot know how to do

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.